# Can't open solution when TFS is offline

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I work with Visual Studio 2015.
Every time when I have problem to connect to TFS (network issue or TFS is down) I can't open solution under source control. VS is just stuck and I can't continue working. I've got an advice from one of my collegues: disable network card on PC, but that sound ridiculous!
I remember when I used VS 2010-2012 - I was able to work offline for sure! I just was receiving a message something like "work offline" and that's it!
But now every time without TFS I cannot work.
I think it should be a matter of settings, but I couldn't find it.
Does someone has a solution for it?

Comment: Are you using [local or server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace) workspaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, solution of disabling of Network card isn't so bad: you just need to:

1. Disable your network
2. Open your solution
3. Enable your network

You will be able to work offline like in previous version of VS.

Comment: Exactly , if you don't want to disable the Network card. Disconnecting WiFi or pull out the network cable both work with my  test. You just need to make sure your network connection to TFS is unavailable or unreliable when you open the solution. Do not need to keep disconnected from the network.

Answer (score 1):

Seems on VS 2010-2012 you are using the **server workspace** which you can simply switch to offline mode.

> **Switch to offline mode when using a server workspace**
>
> When you use a server workspace and cannot connect to your Team
>   Foundation Server, Source Control Explorer is disabled. However, if
>   you have local copies of your files in your server workspace, you can
>   still edit them from Solution Explorer. After the server becomes
>   available again, you can check the changes into version control.

On VS2015 seems you are using the **local workspace**. And the suggestion  by your colleagues is completely right. The straightforward way is just ***disable the network*** and re-open your solution. Then everything will go offline.

> **Work offline with Local workspace**
>
> **You can quickly begin editing a file when your network connection is unavailable or unreliable.** From Solution Explorer you can add, edit,
>   delete, rename, undo, and compare items in your workspace even when
>   you're not connected to your Team Foundation Server.

[More details info](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/decide-between-using-local-server-workspace) with server workspace and local workspace for your reference.

---

If you don't want to disable the network to work offline, you can still use below two options:

- Use the command-line utility in [TFS Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1).
- Use the [Go Offline extension for Visual Studio 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a7cb3430-eb4a-4cc9-9533-c7afaef163de)

Comment: I'm going to try this extension when out TFS will be offline.
Thanks.

Comment: Hello MR.B, any update on this ? Did the extension worked? If it worked ,could you mark it as  answer with an encourage.